# How to input of a string which contain '\n' in it

Tags: c, user-input

I have created an auto typing bot which simulate characters of string given by user.

My code is this:

```
    printf("Enter speed (wpm) (1 to 11750):");
    scanf("%d", &speed);
    if(speed < 1 || speed > 11750) 
    {
        printf("\nPlease provide CORRECT DATA\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Paste the String : \n");
    gets(exaArray);
    exaArrayLength = strlen(exaArray); 
    relation = (int)11750/speed; 
    printf("typing will start in 2 sec-\n");
    Sleep(2000); 
    i=pos=0;

    while(i<=exaArrayLength)
    {
        Sleep(relation);
        if((exaArray[pos]>96) && (exaArray[pos]<123)) //small letters
        {
            keycode=0x41 + (exaArray[pos]%97);
            smallLetter(keycode); //function for key simulation
        }    
        .....
```

I am taking input using gets function. This program works fine when I paste text which does not contain Enter. So this program works fine with one paragraph.
But if the user provides more than one paragraph, then it simulates only the first paragraph.

Because `gets` terminates at '\n'. Which function could take multiple paragraph input and assign it to a string.

Comment: Loop around the reading function, concatenating what had been read so far.

Comment: OT: Aaand do ***not*** use `gets()`, but use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @alk sir, if i use input like this - fgets(s, 20000, stdin); 
would not this statement terminate when there is a Enter or \n in user input?

Comment: @Prabhakarrai Yes it would, but at least you don't have to worry about buffer overflows. Besides, in the latest standard of C, C11, the `gets` function have actually been removed.

Comment: You should pass to `fgets()` as 2nd parameter what the size is of you refer to by the 1st. This is not related to stopping input on reading a new-line, but on code safety.

Comment: Run a google search for "here documents" to see how this problem is handled by `bash`. Another option is to store the string in a file which is then supplied as an argument to the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no way for the computer to make a difference between the user pressing enter and the "pasted" string containing newlines. (Technically, pasting something into the console is like typing it.)

If you just don't want the problem to exit after one paragraph but continue, you can do it as commenter alk suggested (loop around the reading function) - then you would need Ctrl+C to exit the program and then there would technically still be one paragraph at a time written. Depends on what you further want to do with the program.

On the other hand, if you want a way for the user to input all text at once and only then process it, you would need to define something other than "newline" as "end of input" marker, for example something like ESC.

You would do this by using `getchar` instead of `gets` and manually concatenating each char which is entered this way to a string buffer, and if the character has the value `27` (escape key) for instance, you would end the input loop and start outputting.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a very hard and complex problem, and not easy to solve in an automated way.

It would seem like reading in a loop would be a good solution, but then you come to the point when there is no more input and the reading function just blocks waiting for more input. The easiest way out of this is to have the user enter the "end of file" key combination (<kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on POSIX systems like Linux or OSX, <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> on Windows), but the user must then be told to do that.

The problem stems from that your program simply have no idea how much data it is expected to read, and there is no function which is able to, basically, read the users mind when the user thinks "that's it, no more data".

Besides the above solution to have the user give an "end of file", you can use other sequences or special keys or even phrases of input to mark the end, but it all comes down to this: Read input in a loop until users says "no more input".